# Can't solve this limit

Tags: limits

Can someone help me solve this limit?
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}{\log_{e}(e^x+x)+2\over x}$$
I've tried everything I can think of but always get stuck somewhere.

Comment: If you don't realize @hHhh's nice trick below, have you tried l'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: I'm in highschool, haven't learns l'Hopital's rule

Comment: Then apply what hHhh has written below.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is supposed to be an exercise in asymptotics.  For large x, e^x dominates x and the +2 is similarly irrelevant, leaving only log_e(e^x) / x, which is 1.  Not at all thorough, but good for building intuition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if this is enough for you but have you realized that:

\begin{equation}
\log_e(e^x + x) = \log_e(e^x(1+xe^{-x})) = x + \log_e(1 + xe^{-x})
\end{equation}

?

Answer (score 1):

L'Hospital:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2+\ln (x+\exp x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{0+\frac{1+e^x}{x+e^x}}{1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{0+e^x}{1+e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{0+e^x}=1$$

Answer (score -1):

i hope you know that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac x{e^x} = 0  \text{ equivalently } \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^x}{x} = \infty$$ to conclude that $$e^x >>x \text{ for large } x.$$

therefore $$\ln(e^x + x) = \ln(e^x) + \cdots = x+\cdots \text{ for large }x. $$ therefore $$ \lim_{x\to\infty}{\ln(e^x+x)+2\over x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x+2+\cdots}{x} = 1.$$